# Declare a bean as primary in Spring XML

Tags: xml, spring, javabeans

I am trying to use the primary property in the bean tag of my XML as shown below :

```
<bean id = "gslFeatures" class="aero.sita.pts.bcs.common.model.features.GSLFeatures" primary = "true">
    </bean>
```

But I get the below error when I try to run my application :

cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'primary' is not allowed to appear in element 'bean'.

Now the error is pretty self explanatory, but how do I resolve this and make sure that this bean is considered as primary when autowiring.

Comment: what Spring version are you using... I think 'Primary' was introduced with Spring 3.0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use schema version(xsd version) above 2.0 in your xml file. You can find the schema versions in the following link https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/ .

But, the best practice is to not specify the version. In this case, the latest version will be picked up.

Example:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="electricMotor1" class="com.chiranth.ElectricMotor1" primary="true"/>
    <bean id="electricMotor2" class="com.chiranth.ElectricMotor2"/>

    <bean id="modelX" class="com.chiranth.TeslaModelX" autowire="constructor"/>
</beans>
```